# condition variables error in mutex locks

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

Okay so in the code below there at least two major problems which should be corrected.

```
#define COUNT_LIMIT 12
pthread_mutex_t c_mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond_cv;

int count=0;

void *inc_count(void *param)
{
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<14;i++) {
        count++;
        if (count==COUNT_LIMIT)
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond_cv);
    }
}

void *watch_count(void *param)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&c_mutex);
    while (count<COUNT_LIMIT) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond_cv, &c_mutex);
        printf("watch_count(): signal received.\n");
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&c_mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The first problem that I spotted was in the watch_count() function at the while loop, the logic there is wrong because when count is 12, it will not be less than COUNT_LIMIT. So to fix this I would change it to

```
while(count <= COUNT_LIMIT)
```

Would the other thing be unlocking the mutex after signalling watch_count()?

Otherwise, I cannot find any other thing that is wrong. I event tried reading [this](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) but I had trouble understanding it.

Comment: The `while` condition is fine as it is. "when count is 12, it will not be less than COUNT_LIMIT". That is exactly what is wanted. It should keep looping until the count reaches 12. Your change is not required.

Comment: I don't suppose your question comes with some reasonable description of *desired behavior* ?

Answer (score 1):

One error is that the `inc_count()` function needs to have the mutex locked while it accesses the `count` variable.

Your suggested change to the `while()` loop is incorrect - it should *not* call `pthread_cond_wait()` again if `count == COUNT_LIMIT`, so the original test was correct.

The other error might be that `c_mutex` and `cond_cv` are not initialised correctly.